# AWS iOS Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I am trying to setup AWS User Sign in using the AWS Mobile Hub integration.

I have followed every step exactly. However, when I try to run the app I get this error:

> Result: nil AuthState: AWSIdentityManagerAuthState 
>    Error:Optional(Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.})

The application does nothing apart from try to present a login/sign up screen. Yes I have unauthenticated access turned off but that does not mean users shouldn't be able to even sign in??

If I allow unauthenticated access it works.

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: How you solve this? Please answer me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335973/aws-unauthenticated-access-is-not-supported-for-this-identity-pool-in-swift